# IE10+11: XSLT transformation adds arbitrary CR/LF into XML

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I'm struggling with a problem I only encounter with Internet Explorer 10 and 11 while doing client side XSL transformation. My aim is to transform a given XML string containing, among others, the HTML tag `<pre>...</pre>` in order to prepare formatted output.

Carriagereturn-linefeed characters ("\n") are getting lost in the transformation (btw: even when wrapping them into CDATA-containers), and what is even more confusing, after the transformation, the output contains other cr/lfs at arbitrary places.

This is occurring in IE 10/11 solely. No such problems with Chrome or Firefox, neither with Edge!

I know that there is a different handling for XSLT in IE than in the other browers and I already considered two different alternatives in my example, however, both are resulting in the same output.

Please check my following HTML snippet (just try out in IE and Chrome/FF and you'll see what I mean...):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test maker</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xml = "<Actions><action><html><body><pre xml:space=\"preserve\">"
 + "\nThis line is not split and it ends with a dedicated cr-lf.\n"
        + "This is a new line. It also continues until the full-stop, then has a cr-lf.\n"
 + "This is the third and therewith the last line.\n</pre></body></html></action></Actions>"; 

  
var xsl = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
 + "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">"
 + "<xsl:preserve-space elements=\"*\"/>"
        + "<xsl:template match=\"/\"><Actions><xsl:for-each select=\"//action\"><action><description><xsl:apply-templates select=\"html/*\" />"
        + "</description></action></xsl:for-each></Actions></xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"html//pre\"><xsl:text>&lt;code&gt;</xsl:text>"
 + "<xsl:apply-templates select=\"node()\"/><xsl:text>&lt;/code&gt;</xsl:text></xsl:template>"
 + "<xsl:template match=\"text()\"><xsl:value-of select=\".\"/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
 
 
function applyAdapterRule(odtaDocument, ruleData, alt) {
 if (odtaDocument && ruleData) {
        var result = null;
     if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {      // IE
         //IE9 won't recognize the proper codepage
                odtaDocument.charset = "UTF-8";
                odtaDocument.characterSet = "UTF-8";
  odtaDocument.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
  switch(alt) {
    case 1:
                    var srcTree = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
      srcTree.async=false;
      srcTree.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
      srcTree.load(odtaDocument); 
      var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
      xslDoc.async = false;
      xslDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
      xslDoc.load(ruleData);
      return srcTree.transformNode(xslDoc);
    case 2: 
      var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");
      var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");
      xslDoc.async = false;
      xslDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
      xslDoc.load(ruleData);
      xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
      var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
      xslProc.input = odtaDocument;
      xslProc.transform();
      return xslProc.output; 
  }
    
        } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) { // Chrome, Mozilla 
                xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
                xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(ruleData);
                resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(odtaDocument);
                return resultDocument;
        }
 }
};
  
function do_it(alternative) {
            var rule = $.parseXML(xsl);
     var new_xml = "";
            
            var tempDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
//     tempDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
 
            tempDoc = applyAdapterRule(tempDoc, rule, alternative);
            if (typeof tempDoc === "string") {
                new_xml = tempDoc;      // IE
            } else {
                new_xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(tempDoc); // Chrome, Mozilla
            }
     $("#out").replaceWith("<pre>"+new_xml+"</pre>");
};
 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="javascript:do_it(1);">Test 1</button>
<button onclick="javascript:do_it(2);">Test 2</button>
<div><div id="out">See what happens...</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something I'm still doing wrong with the XSL transformation in the IE case?

/edit:

From the above example, I expect the following output (as I get from Chrome and Firefox):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mmpe.jpg)

With my IE11 however, I get this output, no matter if I press the first or the second button (i.e. whether I execute the case 1 or the case 2 branch):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNpJx.jpg)

Comment: ...to run the script in IE (which is the question here) it might be necessary to copy&paste the code into a local HTML file and open it with the IE. I just noticed that the ActiveX-Objects won't get instantiated properly when just using the [run code snippet]-button - sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain and show in a code snippet the result you expect from the XSLT transformation. I am not sure what you are looking for and mixing the browsers' APIs for XML parsing and serialization with additional parsing and serialization through JQuery makes it difficult to understand what the problem is and where it comes from. A simple test case using IE's MSXML API and then simply outputting the transformNode result in a text node of the HTML document at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016051201.html does not show any problems as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have tried to extend the previous test to also work with browsers supporting `XSLTProcessor`, now I have http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016051202.html, as far as I can tell the result is the same in terms of white space in IE 11 and Firefox 46 and Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: Hi Martin. Maybe you already helped me a lot! In your test case you are using the method `loadXML()` to load the XML into the MSXML object - which seem to work correctly.
I was using the method `load()` for this matter. This could have caused the problem?!
I will test a little bit with this "new information for me" and let you know if it really fixes my problem...
Thanks already at this point!

Comment: Hi again. Yes, that's it! Thanks so much, Martin! When using method `loadXML()` and feeding the MSXML objects with XML / XSLT as flat strings, the transformation works as expected. 
When feeding the objects via `load()`and in that case, the arguments must be structured XML objects, the problem occurs as reported above.
Without understanding the deeper sense of that, I can live with this solution :-)

Comment: I will morph the comment and linked code into an answer so that you can mark the issue as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE, I would suggest to simply use the MSXML APIs directly and not mix JQuery with the MSXML APIs. Using the code in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2016051202.html which basically loads your `xml` and `xsl` strings as MSXML DOM documents in

```
var xml = "<Actions><action><html><body><pre xml:space=\"preserve\">"
    + "\nThis line is not split and it ends with a dedicated ctrl-lf.\n"
        + "This is a new line. It also continues until the full-stop, then has a ctrl-lf.\n"
    + "This is the third and therewith the last line.\n<\/pre><\/body><\/html><\/action><\/Actions>";   


var xsl = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    + "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">"
    + "<xsl:preserve-space elements=\"*\"/>"
        + "<xsl:template match=\"/\"><Actions><xsl:for-each select=\"//action\"><action><description><xsl:apply-templates select=\"html/*\" />"
        + "<\/description><\/action><\/xsl:for-each><\/Actions><\/xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"html//pre\"><xsl:text>&lt;code&gt;<\/xsl:text>"
    + "<xsl:apply-templates select=\"node()\"/><xsl:text>&lt;/code&gt;<\/xsl:text><\/xsl:template>"
    + "<xsl:template match=\"text()\"><xsl:value-of select=\".\"/><\/xsl:template><\/xsl:stylesheet>";

function test1() {
    if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined' && typeof XSLTProcessor != 'undefined') {
        var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
        var sheet = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xsl, 'application/xml');

        var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        proc.importStylesheet(sheet);

        var resultDoc = proc.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
        var result = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);

        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.textContent = result;
        document.getElementById('test1').appendChild(pre);
    }
    else  {
        try {
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);

            var sheet = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
            sheet.loadXML(xsl);

            var result = xmlDoc.transformNode(sheet);

            var pre = document.createElement('pre');
            pre.textContent = result;

            document.getElementById('test1').appendChild(pre);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    test1();
}
```

the transformation result has the original line breaks preserved:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Actions><action><description>&lt;code&gt;
This line is not split and it ends with a dedicated ctrl-lf.
This is a new line. It also continues until the full-stop, then has a ctrl-lf.
This is the third and therewith the last line.
&lt;/code&gt;</description></action></Actions>
```

Comment: ...just want to clear up one point:

I do not believe that the issue is the mixture of JQuery and the MSXML APIs! 

Moreover, it seems to me as if only the method `load()` causes the problem. In Martins snippet above, the method `loadXML()`is used and this one works fine (for me, switching to that method was the solution).

I tried Martin's code but substituted `xmlDoc.loadXML(xml)` with `xmlDoc.load(xmlObj)` (after converting the `string xml` into an `Object xmlObj`) and therewith, the problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

So when I substitute the method `xmlDoc.loadXML(xml)` with `xmlDoc.load(xmlObj)`, the code looks like this:

```
var xml = "<Actions><action><html><body><pre xml:space=\"preserve\">"
    + "\nThis line is not split and it ends with a dedicated ctrl-lf.\n"
    + "This is a new line. It also continues until the full-stop, then has a ctrl-lf.\n"
    + "This is the third and therewith the last line.\n<\/pre><\/body><\/html><\/action><\/Actions>";   


var xsl = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    + "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">"
    + "<xsl:preserve-space elements=\"*\"/>"
    + "<xsl:template match=\"/\"><Actions><xsl:for-each select=\"//action\"><action><description><xsl:apply-templates select=\"html/*\" />"
    + "<\/description><\/action><\/xsl:for-each><\/Actions><\/xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"html//pre\"><xsl:text>&lt;code&gt;<\/xsl:text>"
    + "<xsl:apply-templates select=\"node()\"/><xsl:text>&lt;/code&gt;<\/xsl:text><\/xsl:template>"
    + "<xsl:template match=\"text()\"><xsl:value-of select=\".\"/><\/xsl:template><\/xsl:stylesheet>";

function test1() {
    if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined' && typeof XSLTProcessor != 'undefined') {
        var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
        var sheet = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xsl, 'application/xml');

        var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        proc.importStylesheet(sheet);

        var resultDoc = proc.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
        var result = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);

        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.textContent = result;
        document.getElementById('test1').appendChild(pre);
    }
    else  {
        try {

            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');

            var xmlObj = $.parseXML(xml);      //convert XML String to XML Object
            xmlDoc.load(xmlObj);               //use load() instead of loadXML() 

            var sheet = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
            sheet.loadXML(xsl);

            var result = xmlDoc.transformNode(sheet);

            var pre = document.createElement('pre');
            pre.textContent = result;

            document.getElementById('test1').appendChild(pre);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    test1();
}
```

and the resulting output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Actions><action><description>&lt;code&gt;This line is not split and it ends with a dedicated 
ctrl-lf. This is a new line. It also continues until the full-stop, then has a 
ctrl-lf. This is the third and therewith the last line. 
&lt;/code&gt;</description></action></Actions>
```